# How to add linear gradient to images in Materializecss' slider

Tags: html, css, materialize

I'm coding a website with the CSS framework "Materializecss", but I'm struggling with the slider. I would like to have a linear gradient over every image on the slider so that the text on the image can be read better (this is the linear gradient I want     linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5))      ) but I cannot understand how to do it

PS i know i can do it by linking the image in the css as I did it for an hero in another page, but i want to have it linked in an  tag as it is now. Anyone have any solution?

Here's the code:

```
<div class="slider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
  <img src="images/tema.jpg">
  <div class="caption center">
    <h2>Chi siamo?</h2>
    <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Per saperne di più</h5>
    <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">clicca qui</a>
  </div>
</li>
<li>
  <img src="images/studenti1.jpg"> <!-- random image -->
  <div class="caption center">
    <h2>Progetti</h2>
    <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Per saperne di più</h5>
    <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">clicca qui</a>
  </div>
</li>
<li>
  <img src="images/studenti2.jpg"> <!-- random image -->
  <div class="caption center">
    <h2>Foto</h2>
    <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Per saperne di più</h5>
    <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">clicca qui</a>
  </div>
</li>
<li>
  <img src="images/studenti3.jpg"> <!-- random image -->
  <div class="caption center">
    <h2>Abbigliamento</h2>
    <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Per saperne di più</h5>
    <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">clicca qui</a>
  </div>
</li>
<li>
  <img src="images/studenti4.jpg"> <!-- random image -->
  <div class="caption center">
    <h2>Contatti</h2>
    <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Per saperne di più</h5>
    <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">clicca qui</a>
  </div>
</li>
<li>
  <img src="images/studenti1.jpg"> <!-- random image -->
  <div class="caption center">
    <h2>News</h2>
    <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Per saperne di più</h5>
    <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">clicca qui</a>
  </div>
</li>
<li>
  <img src="images/studenti2.jpg"> <!-- random image -->
  <div class="caption center">
    <h2>Cogestione</h2>
    <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Per saperne di più</h5>
    <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">clicca qui</a>
  </div>
</li>
<li>
  <img src="images/studenti3.jpg"> <!-- random image -->
  <div class="caption center">
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Per saperne di più</h5>
    <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">clicca qui</a>
  </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to do this:

```
.your image {
    max-width: 100%;  //or what you want
    width: 800px;  //or what you want
    margin: auto;  //or what you want
}

.your image::after {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5))
    margin-top: -150px;  //or what you want
    height: 150px;  //or what you want
    width: 100%;  //or what you want
    content: '';
}
```

Comment: I've already tried but no good results... I've even tried to put a div around the img with te cass .your image and your css, but nothing...

Comment: You can check here: https://peter.coffee/how-to-use-css-pseudo-elements-to-add-a-gradient-to-images

Comment: OP asks about how-to for the `img` tag, and those can't have pseudo elements, so an answer like this needs both a proper sample and an explanation.